# Visual Studio IIS project HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Current is null

Tags: c#, authentication, iis

Recently acquired a website project using C# IIS/Visual Studio.

Just running it up and viewing a page gives me error's about Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
System.NullReferenceException.

Traced it back to HttpContext.Current.User.Identity being null.
The application uses forms authentication.

I did find a solution so I wanted to post it here to save others/myself time in the future.

Comment: WebForms pages should use `Page.User` to access the user identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click the Web Project in the Solution Explorer.
2. Press F4 / Click Properties.
3. Change Managed Pipeline Mode from Integrated to Classic.

Save & Debug/Run site.